# how to list windows per KDE/Plasma5 Activity

Tags: kde-plasma

I am trying to write a script that launches an app if not running or activates the window if already visible in the current activity.

Using `xdotool` or `wmctrl` I am able to get the list of windows and activate them. If they are not open, then I can launch them. But the problem comes with KDE Activities. These tools list windows from all the activities even if they are not visible in current activity.

I am going through various qdbus methods but not finding anything close.

have anyone created such scripts? how one could get the windows visibility with respect to the activities?

Edits:
as shown in the picture below , I was able to see the activity IDs that the window is attached to. But I am not able to find any way to get it programmatically.

[image]

Comment: I can't imagine that there isn't a way to do that. I mean, obviously the task-manager knows about this as it is able to show only windows of the current activity, but I'm too bad at C to figure out if I can use it (code @ https://github.com/KDE/plasma-desktop/blob/master/applets/taskmanager/plugin/backend.cpp).... I also hoped that maybe checking dbus with something like `qdbus org.kde.ActivityManager /ActivityManager/Resources/Linking IsResourceLinkedToActivity :global <PID> :current` would help (see https://github.com/alxlg/ff-kactivities/blob/master/ff-kactivities), but nope.. Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative aproach was given [in kde forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=166979). But it is not completely clear if it can help solve your issue.

The recommendation is as follows:

> On the activity level you can make use of URI > Activity relations and
> query dbus for further scripting. For example:
>
> 1. Link a directory to an activity in dolphin.
> 2. Add an application "dolphin-directive" to application launcher and make it run a custom script to conditionally start dolphin instances.
> 3. Set "dolphin-directive" as default filemanager
>
> A similar workflow is possible for each filetype via File Association
> Settings

As far as I could figure out through experiments it is not possible to link windows to activities and query relations via ActivityManager. I guess *the multiple-screen-workspace-uri-activity-window-rule architecture* is supposed to setup workflows to solve the problem in a **more holistic manner**. But hopefully someone can give a better answer here.

[I wrote a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203410/how-to-list-all-object-paths-under-a-dbus-service/624863#624863) to regex inspect the whole session bus tree for related and usefull methods. You can simply use it by `./query-dbus.py --pattern "^.*activit.*$"`. So the answer is work in progress.

EDIT: some services do have the method `isMonitorActivity`, `isOnActivity`

```
"org.kde.konsole": {
    "/Sessions/1": {
      "org.kde.konsole.Session": {
          "method": [
            "setMonitorActivity",
            "isMonitorActivity"
          ]
      }
    }
}
    

"org.kde.kate": {
    "/MainApplication": {
      "org.kde.Kate.Application": {
          "method": [
            "isOnActivity"
          ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Did you already file a feature request?

Comment: there is actually the dbus method
```
org.kde.ActivityManager "/ActivityManager/Resources/Linking"
```
to listen for window linking to activities. But I wasn't able to complete my experiment successfully.

Comment: I was the one posting that question in the forum:)
I posted a screenshot that might also be helpful to you.

Comment: Unfortunately I am lacking 9 reputation scores to comment your post. So:
Awesome! I've also looked into the that console you mentioned and found the window's resourceName, which I need to query the Link by calling ActivityManager/Resource/Linking/isResourceLinkedToActivity method.

Comment: Please post if you comeup with a script.

Comment: How did your experiment with "/ActivityManager/Resources/Linking" look like?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jnoortheen/d777fc422e603c2ba0f2415ed2bfe80b

Comment: btw just measured the much more elegant qdbus solution to list dbus but it unexpectedly took 15 seconds more on my slow machine.
thanks for the additional input.
Did you solve your issue in a different way by now?

Comment: I just  moved on to single activity at a time. It was taking too much to find a way.